# Playing video from NSData in objective c

Tags: objective-c, caching, avplayer

I have video's NSData and stored in my cache. I want to play this on AVPlayer (or some other player if iOS has) but not able to understand that in which format should I convert NSData so that it can be played on AVplayer. I don't want to save it locally and then give filepath's to AVplayer to play video.
Kindly suggest is there any other way to play video from NSData.I have already spent 3 days on it  but couldn't reach to any conclusion.Kindly give your suggestion.Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you the solution which gets the NSData from cache and plays the video.

**STEP 1:Add the AVKit framework in Target->BuilPhases->Link Binary With Libraries**

**STEP 2:Then import in ViewController.Now it looks like below.**

ViewController.h

```
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
```

**STEP 3:Declare the  AVPlayerViewController as Strong in ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
- (IBAction)actionPlayVideo:(id)sender;

@end
```

**STEP 4:Get the path from cache and convert to URL.Then finally play the video**

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSURL *vedioURL;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize playerViewController;

- (IBAction)actionPlayVideo:(id)sender{
    NSString *strNSDataPath = [[self getNSDataFromCache] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourSavedNSDataName"];
    vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strNSDataPath];
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:vedioURL];
    AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    playerViewController.player = playVideo;
    playerViewController.player.volume = 0;
    playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    [playVideo play];
}
-(NSString *)getNSDataFromCache{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachesDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return cachesDirectory;
}
```