# How to play an video in an AVPlayer using the videoID for the searched item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

I built an iOS app for showing the video for the searched item, the problem occurred is as follows:

1. I used the YouTube data api and extracted the `videoId`.
2. I am not able to add this to an `AVPlayer` (but when YouTube player used I was able to add the `videoId`, for example like this:

   `[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:self.strngvideoId];
    [self.view addSubview:_playerView];`
3. I want to use only `AVPlayer` and no other players, how can fix this issue?

   I want to pass the `videoId` in the `AVPlayer` and play the video.

Comment: i have done But with MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj can you tell how you done with it...only the code section that you used with videoID...thnks in advance

Comment: if you still want the code. i will share

Comment: @ ajjjjjjjj ...plz share

Comment: @Roby Please check this link https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit

Comment: @ajjjjjjjj..thanku...I solved my issue in my app...thanks for that tutorial link....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to play the video you have to use AVPlayerViewController.First import AVKit framework in your project.Below code works perfectly.

In ViewController.h I imported the AVKit framework.Before that we need to add in Target->BuildPhases->Link Binary With Libraries

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
- (IBAction)actionPlayVideo:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSURL *vedioURL;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize playerViewController;

- (IBAction)actionPlayVideo:(id)sender{
   vedioURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strngvideoId];
   AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:vedioURL];
   AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
   playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
   playerViewController.player = playVideo;
   playerViewController.player.volume = 0;
   playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
   [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
   [playVideo play];
}
```

[Playing Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44093958/playing-video-from-nsdata-in-objective-c/44099703#44099703)